# Jenkins: Is there a way to specify order of jobs on call to run 3 jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have a job I call Deploy-Production-Hook (This calls CI-Chrome, CI-Firefox and CI-IE). It would be nice if it would always build CI-IE first. Because this is the slowest.

Is there anyway in the Comma Separated list to build IE first?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Jenkins 2.0 pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/overview/) or [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) instead of simple downstream job relation.